# OrientDB: Movies tutorial

Tags: orientdb

I am trying to use OrientDB to perform gremlin queries through a select statement. I'm sure I saw a tutorial doing just this using the movies example from the demo database. However, I have read through so much documentation on the DB that I can't for the life of me find it now. Does anybody have a link to it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the tutorial that you are looking for is this one

http://markorodriguez.com/2011/09/22/a-graph-based-movie-recommender-engine/

is not with orientdb but neo4j.

Since both support gremlin and orientdb is 100% compilant with blueprints the tutorial is applicable to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of presentations [here](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Presentations)